# Given the correlation of A to B, how can one find (or approximate) the correlation of B to A?

Tags: statistics

Here's the situation:

I'm looking to correlate income and asset data. The objective is to find out what portion of people in a certain income group also fall in a certain "wealth" group. Our data source is table C [here](https://www.federalreserve.gov/econres/notes/feds-notes/wealth-and-income-concentration-in-the-scf-20200928.htm) where we are told the correlation of wealth to income group.

In a set of statements, we are told: "49 percent of the top 1 by wealth are also in the top 1 by augmented income"

I'm looking to say: "*x* percent of the bottom 50 by augmented income are also in the bottom 50 by wealth," reversing the correlation without much/any population information.

Is this possible or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Assuming the same population is being analysed both times, "49 percent of the top 1 percent by wealth are also in the top 1 percent by augmented income" means $49\%\times 1\%= 0.49\%$ of the population are in both categories so $\frac{0.49\%}{1\%} =49\%$ of the top 1 percent by augmented income are also in the top 1 percent by wealth.

Comment: From table C you can do similar calculations of multiplication and division (with some minor rounding issues) so for example for the bottom 50 percent by income, about $72\%$ are in the bottom 50 bottom percent by wealth, about $27\%$ are in the next 40 percent by wealth, about $0.5\%$ are in the next 9 percent by wealth and about $0.1\%$ are in the top 1 percent by wealth.  Similarly with some addition, you can say about $5\%$ of the top 10 percent by income are in the bottom 50 percent by wealth, which may for example be people like young doctors with high debts.